Cómo manejar errores decimales por conversión de tipos
les comento mi situación.
Estoy resolviendo ejercicios de CodeSignal y me encontré con el siguiente:

Algunas personas corren en línea recta en la misma dirección.
Comienzan simultáneamente en posiciones distintas por pares y corren a
velocidad constante (que puede diferir de persona a persona).
Si dos o más personas están en el mismo punto en algún momento lo
llamamos reunión. Al número de personas reunidas en un mismo punto se
le llama cardinalidad de reunión.
Para las posiciones iniciales y velocidades dadas de los corredores,
encuentre la cardinalidad máxima de encuentro suponiendo que las
personas corren infinitamente. Si no habrá reuniones, devuelva
-1 en su lugar.
Ejemplo
Para startPosition = [1, 4, 2] y speed = [27, 18, 24], la salida debe
ser solución (posición inicial, velocidad) = 3.
A los 20 segundos de empezar a correr los corredores llegan al mismo
punto, como se ve a continuación:


El arreglo startPosition describe las posiciones iniciales en "metros" y la velocidad viene dada en metros/minuto.
Mi primer intento de solución fue a través de un ciclo, pero es tardado y las pruebas tienen tiempo límite de ejecución, así que opté por una solución más analítica. La idea es:
Para cada uno de los corredores, encontrar el segundo en el que se encuentran con otro y contar el número de corredores que se encuentran en ese segundo. Si el número equivale a la cantidad de corredores, detengo la comprobación. Mi código es el siguiente:
int solution(int[] startPosition, int[] speed) {
    int maxMeets = -1;
    int seconds, cardinality;
    for(int i=0; i<(startPosition.length-1); i++) {
        for(int j=(i+1); j<startPosition.length; j++) {
            seconds = secondsToMeet(startPosition[i], startPosition[j], speed[i], speed [j]);
            if(seconds >= 0) {
                cardinality = meetingsAtSecond(seconds, startPosition, speed);
                if(cardinality > maxMeets) {
                    maxMeets = cardinality;
                    if(maxMeets == startPosition.length) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(maxMeets == startPosition.length) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return maxMeets;
}

//Si ambos corredores coinciden, se devuelve el segundo. Si no, se devuelve -1
public int secondsToMeet(int pos1, int pos2, int vel1, int vel2) {
    int secs = -1;
    try {
        secs = (pos2*100 - pos1*100) / (vel1*100/60 - vel2*100/60);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return (secs<0) ? -1 : secs;
}

//Calcula la posición para todos los corredores en un segundo determinado y devuelve
//la cantidad máxima de corredores que se encuentran en ese segundo
//en un mismo punto. Devuelve -1 si no hay más de 1 corredor en cada
//posición calculada
public int meetingsAtSecond(int second, int positions[], int speeds[]){
    int max = -1;
    BigDecimal posAct, posOrig, distPerSec, sec = new BigDecimal(second);
    Map<BigDecimal, Integer> posAfterXSec = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<positions.length; i++) {
        distPerSec = new BigDecimal(speeds[i]/60.0F).setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        posOrig = new BigDecimal(positions[i]);
        posAct = posOrig.add(distPerSec.multiply(sec)).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
                //positions[i] +  second * speeds[i]/60.0F;
        //System.out.println("Pos: " + posAct);
        posAfterXSec.compute(posAct, (k,v) -> (v==null) ? 1 : v+1);
    }
    //System.out.println("Positions at sec " + second + ", : " + posAfterXSec);
    for(Map.Entry<BigDecimal,Integer> entry : posAfterXSec.entrySet()) {
        if((entry.getValue() > 1) && (entry.getValue()>max)) {
            max = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return max;
}

Mi problema radica en que la división entre 60 acarrea muchos errores decimales, y tuve que buscar otras soluciones. Para el método secondsToMeet, lo pude solucionar multiplicando por 100 todos los valores, pero para el segundo método no funcionó.
En algún post de aquí encontré que la mejor opción era usar la clase BigDecimal (actualmente implementada), pero aún así sigue fallando. Por ejemplo, para lo valores:
int pos[] = {1,1000};
int vel[] = {23,22};

Estoy encontrando que el segundo en el que coinciden es el 49 950, pero las posiciones calculadas en el mapa son {19317=1, 19147=1} (ambos valores incorrectos por la presición).
¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo manejar esos decimales?

Dado que los valores de coma flotante pueden no coincidir en una igualdad debido a la precisión, deberías tener en cuenta un margen aceptable entre dos valores (si mal no recuerdo se suele designar como epsilon) para considerar que dos corredores o más están en el mismo lugar. Al multiplicarlo por 100 estás haciendo que la precisión aumente cuando trabajas con números enteros, pero deberías hacerlo en coma flotante comparando que el valor absoluto de la diferencia sea inferior a ese epsilon dado.

Hola Agro88, en mi humilde opinión, aparte de lo terriblemente mal planteado del problema, no hace falta usar decimales, si actualizas las posiciones cada 20 segundos, avanzando de 9, 6 y 8 metros respectivamente, coinciden en los 10 metros, por otro lado, si tienen velocidades distintas, después del primer encuentro, jamás se reuniran.

Hola OscarGarcia. Tambièn intenté hacer uso de sólo 2 decimales tomando el factor de 100, pero aún así no cuadraban los resultados.

Hola Marce Puente. Tal vez no fui lo suficientemente claro en el planteamiento. El test que pongo como ejemplo es sólo uno de más de 12 que realiza la plataforma. Los constraints asegurados son:
(1). La longitud del array speed será la misma que la longitud del array startPosition
(2). La longitud de ambos arrays puede estar entre 2 y 1000
(3). El array startPosition puede contener valores entre -10 000 y 10 000
(4). El array speed puede contener valores entre 1 y 100

Entiendo, el problema es que así como está planteado, es imposible, salvo que actualices las posiciones cada 1 minuto, en cuyo caso manejarías solo números enteros,

Si en la función "secondsToMeet" manejas las divisiones como de tipo "float" y después conviertes a tipo "int" salen bien las cosas.
public int secondsToMeet(int pos1, int pos2, int vel1, int vel2) {
    int secs = -1;
    try {
        float secsf = (pos2 - pos1) / (vel1/60f - vel2/60f);
        secs = (int)secsf;
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return (secs<0) ? -1 : secs;
}


Muchas gracias Armando, en efecto con ese cambio el código pasa todos los tests
